# Как реализовать select с подвязкой под xml файл?

Tags: php, jquery, css, xml

Есть стандартный *select*, в котором будет осуществляться выбор дилеров. Есть xml файл с данными по этих диллерах. 
Как подключить этот файл в *select*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример xml файла:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<DealersInfo>
   <Dealer>
      <Title>name 1</Title>
   </Dealer>
   <Dealer>
      <Title>name 2</Title>
   </Dealer>
   <Dealer>
      <Title>name 3</Title>
   </Dealer>
</DealersInfo>
```

Html:

```
<select name="test" id="test_select">
  <option>Выберите диллера</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.xml", //ваш xml файл
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml),
      $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    $xml.find('Dealer').each(function() {
      //test_select - id селекта
      $('<option>').text($(this).find('Title').text()).appendTo($('#test_select'));
      /*
      или(способ 2)
          $("#test_select").append('<option>$(this).find('Title').text()</option>');
      или(способ 3, более медленный)
          $('#test_select').append($('<option>', {
              value: $(this).find('Title').text(), // или поставьте свое значение value
              text : $(this).find('Title').text()
          }));
      */
    });
  }
});
```